# geth 1.8.15 flag provided but not defined: --fast

Tags: go-ethereum, fast-sync

Geth version I have:

```
Version: 1.8.15-unstable
Architecture: amd64
Protocol Versions: [63 62]
Network Id: 1
Go Version: go1.11
Operating System: linux
GOPATH=
GOROOT=/usr/local/go
```

go version:

```
$ which go
/usr/bin/go
$ go version
go version go1.11 linux/amd64
$ echo $GOROOT
(Blank line)
```

---

```
geth --fast --cache=1024 ...
```

The error I am receiving:

```
flag provided but not defined: -fast
```

---

I was able to use `--fast` flag on the previous versions but now I cannot.
Is is because `--fast` flag removed or something else. How could I fix this error? Is there any alternative flag for `--fast`?

=> Similar [issue](https://github.com/astaxie/beego/issues/2859).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use flag `--syncmode fast` instead

they already update the wiki document https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options

> **DEPRECATED OPTIONS:**
>
> --fast   Enable fast syncing through state downloads (replaced by --syncmode)
>
> --light  Enable light client mode (replaced by --syncmode)

Comment: It works! what is difference between `--fast` and `--syncmode fast`? @Ha ĐANG

Comment: no difference, `--fast` is just a shortcut for `--syncmode fast` and they remove this shortcut in version 1.8.15